# Error inside where clause while comparing items in Spark SQL

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have cloudera vm running spark version 1.6.0

I created a dataframe from a CSV file and now filtering columns based on some where clause

```
df = sqlContext.read.format('com.databricks.spark.csv').options(header='true').load('file:///home/cloudera/sample.csv')
df.registerTempTable("closedtrips")

result = sqlContext.sql("SELECT id,`safety rating` as safety_rating, route FROM closedtrips WHERE `trip frozen` == 'YES'")
```

However it gives me runtime error on the sql line.

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o21.sql.
: java.lang.RuntimeException: [1.96] failure: identifier expected

SELECT consigner,`safety rating` as safety_rating, route FROM closedtrips WHERE `trip frozen` == 'YES'
                                                                                               ^
```

Where am I going wrong here?

The above command fails in vm command line, however works fine when ran on databricks environment

Also why are column names case sensitive in vm, it fails to recognise 'trip frozen' because the actual column is 'Trip Frozen'. 
All of this works fine in databricks and breaks in vm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your VM, are you creating `sqlContext` as a `SQLContext` or as a `HiveContext`?

In Databricks, the automatically-created `sqlContext` will always point to a `HiveContext`.

In Spark 2.0 this distinction between `HiveContext` and regular `SQLContext` should not matter because both have been subsumed by `SparkSession`, but in Spark 1.6 the two types of contexts differ slightly in how they parse SQL language input.

Comment: I am defining it as sqlcontext, sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
If I define it as hivecontext, the case sensitivity issue will be resolved?

Comment: I believe that this should probably fix the `failure: identifier expected` issue; I'm not sure offhand about the case sensitivity.